# cant get opengl es 2.0 to render a triangle

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have been trying to learn opengl and I cant seem to get a triangle to render my code should work it will render the clearColor I set it to but not the triangle and my vertex and fragment shaders return no error can anyone see the problem please and thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    public static int POSITION_ATTRIBUTE = 0;
    public int program;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(this);
    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config)
{
    // Vertex Shader Source Code
    String vertexShaderSource = "" +
        "attribute vec2 position; \n" +
        "\n" +
        "void main() \n" +
        "{ \n" +
        "   gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0); \n" +
        "} \n" +
        "\n";

    String fragmentShaderSource = "" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "void main() \n" +
        "{ \n" +
        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); \n" +
        "} \n" +
        "\n";

    // Write and compile vertex shader
    int vertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    Log.i("Vertex Shader", "Compile Log: " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));

    // Write and compile fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    Log.i("Fragment Shader", "Compile Log: " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));

    // Link the shaders into a program object
    program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    // Links the variables
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, POSITION_ATTRIBUTE, "position");
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
    Log.i("Link", "Link Log: " + GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.3f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(POSITION_ATTRIBUTE);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height)
{

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused)
{
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Give OpenGl a triangle to render
    float[] geometry = new float[]{
        -0.2f, 0.3f,
        0.4f, 0.5f,
        0.1f, 0.1f,
    };

    ByteBuffer geometryByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(geometry.length * 4);
    geometryByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer geometryBuffer = geometryByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    geometryBuffer.put(geometry);
    geometryBuffer.rewind();
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_ATTRIBUTE, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, geometryBuffer);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, geometry.length / 2);
}
```

}

Comment: If this is the complete code, then one thing you're missing are the hooks for `onPause()` and `onResume()`. See the `GLSurfaceView` documentation.

Comment: I know i was missing those that wasnt the issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue was i forgot GLES20 .gl_Useprogram(program);